# how to put current iteration number as array index in xsl

Tags: xml, xslt, foreach, tags, iteration

Xml I am using

```
"<default>"
    "<string>a</string>"
    "<string>Apple</string>"
    "<string>b</string>"
    "<string>Ball</string>"
    "<string>c</string>"
    "<string>Cat</string>"
    "<string>d</string>"
    "<string>Dog</string>"
"</default>"

and this is the xsl I am using

  <xsl:for-each select="//default/string">
        <xsl:element name="{/default/string[?]\">
             <xsl:value-of select="/default/string[?]\"/>
        </xsl:element>
  </xsl:for-each>
```

Now I want my xml to be in this format

```
<default>
   <a>Apple</a>
   <b>Ball</b>
   <c>Cat</c>
   <d>Dog</d>
</default>
```

For this I need the current iteration number in `<xsl:element name="{/default/string[?]\">` and incremented value in `<xsl:value-of select="/default/string[?]\"/>`
. Can anybody help me in this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are looking for the `position()` function e.g. inside the `for-each` using `<xsl:value-of select="position()"/>` will yield `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, etc.

```
<xsl:for-each select="//default/string">
  <xsl:element name="{.}"><xsl:value-of select="position()"/></xsl:element>
</xsl:for-each>
```

I think your recent edit does not use any index or position, instead you want

```
<xsl:for-each select="//default/string[position() mod 2 = 1]">
  <xsl:element name="{.}"><xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::string[1]"/></xsl:element>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: hey @martin: I am half way down using ur approach but still it is not the format I want. I have edited the question pls have a look on it again.

Comment: @Pulkit, I have added some code to try to implement your changed requirements.